# PHPmyAdmin #1932 - doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, debian

I installed phpmyadmin on Debian. I copied the database folder from an old server into the current MySQL folder. Then came the error # 1932 - Table doesn't exist in engine. I also copied the ibdata1 but to no avail. What can I do?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Copying the data/files works only if

1. It is the same database server version till the subversion
2. You have to copy **all** files from the data directory.

You can tryto upgrade the database for that consult the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html)

Comment: Can I somehow find out the old mysql version that was installed with the files, since I no longer have mysql installed?

Comment: when the old server is running yes, else no